# Let $k$ be a non-algebraically closed field and $I\subset k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ be maximal ideal. Is $V_{\bar{k}}(I)$ necessarily finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ideals

Let $k$ be a non-algebraically closed field and $I\subset k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ be a maximal ideal.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Is $V_{\bar{k}}(I)=\{x\in\bar{k}^n\vert \forall f\in I, f(x)=0\}$ necessarily finite?

Comment: That set is finite because it bijectively corresponds to the $k$-algebra morphisms $F:= k[x_1,\dots, x_n]\to \overline k$. Since $F$ is finite over $k$ this  set of morphisms is finite. I could have given a detailed answer, including an explanation of why this wonderfully illustrates Grothendieck's point of view of schemes as functors, if it were not for the unfortunate and indefensible  decision of five users to close this excellent and natural question.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I am sorry that I missed your comment. Would you like to point me to the reference elucidating the grothendieck's view of schemes as functors here? It seems that EGA does not touch functor of points view in the first 2 vols or I have completely missed it. Thanks.

Comment: Dear user, I recommend Manin's wonderful book [Introduction to the Theory of Schemes](https://books.google.fr/books?id=S7taDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr#v=onepage&q&f=false). The first few sections of Chapter 1 are the best introduction to the functor point of view on affine schemes. Actually the book originates from a very old course Manin gave in Moscow in the 1960's. A translation/adaptation  into English by Leites of the notes from the course (which was given in Russian, of course.) can be freely downloaded [here](http://conteudo.icmc.usp.br/pessoas/grossi/Sasha/galg/manin.pdf).

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thanks a lot for the book. I will look into chpt 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Let $R=k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ and $\overline{R}=\overline{k}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$. Then $\overline{R}$ is an integral extension of $R$ and both rings are normal domains, and we may apply going up and going down to see that $V_{\overline{k}}(I)$ also has dimension zero, and the dimension zero closed subsets of affine space are precisely finite collections of points.

Alternatively, pick a generating set for $I$ and note that there are finitely many polynomials each of finite degree in this set, so we may adjoin a finite number of algebraic elements over $k$ so that all of our generating polynomials factor completely. So over some finite extension, our ideal is now a finite product of ideals of the form $(x_1-a_1,x_2-a_2,\cdots)$. Clearly the base change of this to the algebraic closure has finitely many points, but it's the same as the base change up to the algebraic closure of our original variety.

Comment: Very nice answer:+1.